# Break RegEx matching mid-pattern

Tags: regex

I am writing a RegEx that matches multiple terms:

```
((a)|(b)|(c(1|2)))x
```

I want both the `a` and `c1|2` terms to only match if followed by `x`, but in `b`'s case, I want to stop matching right then and there, ignoring the `x` at the end.

The simple solution would be to move `b` outside of this pattern, but in my case I have multiple nested levels which makes this impossible.

So, is there a way to break inside a RegEx and force the parser to return the current match, ignoring the rest of the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the backtracking control verb `(*ACCEPT)`:

```
(?:a|b(*ACCEPT)|c[12])x
```

See [`perldoc perlre`](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#(*ACCEPT)-(*ACCEPT:arg)):

> `(*ACCEPT)` `(*ACCEPT:arg)`
>
> This pattern matches nothing and causes the end of successful matching at the point at which the `(*ACCEPT)` pattern was encountered, regardless of whether there is actually more to match in the string.

Comment: +1 for showing me something I didn't know about, but OP never specified which regex flavor they're using, and I think this is only available in PCRE.

Comment: @CAustin It's also available in Perl. Anyway, if no language is specified, I assume any regex dialect can be used to answer the question.

Comment: It seems that std::regex and boost are not aware of this syntax .. maybe there is a more common syntax for this behavior available